# mix angular with asp.net mvc views

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

What we have is an Asp.Net MVC site that we want to transition to an AngularJS-WebAPI site. That means we will have both .html and .cshtml pages in the same project.  I solved the problem of sharing the OAuth tokens.  I can also navigate around most of the menu choices. That means I can move around the angular pages and I can move around the mvc pages.  I can also move from the angular pages to the mvc pages.  The problem manifests itself when I try to navigate from mvc pages back to the angular ones. Once the server side routing takes over from the client routing it won't let get.

I've spent the past couple of days trying all sorts of ideas that I gleaned from StackOverflow and various blogs with no luck. Most of the advice is about how to host Angular inside MVC pages and that is not what I am looking for.  I've tried telling MVC routing to "IgnoreRoute"s as well as tried to tell it to funnel all angular routes through a dedicated MVC controller. There were multiple responses on SO that involved complex programming in Angular that I had a hard time understanding and eventually rejected because I don't believe Angular should be that difficult. I only found one comment on a posting that said you should not even bother to try mixing the two paradigms.

Does anyone have a solution to mixing an Angular SPA page with MVC pages? How can I get MVC to route back to my Angular SPA page?

Comment: No simple answer on how you need to code this or set up web.config  but the angular routing basics are fairly simple. You always have to deliver the app entry point from server and let angular manage any paths in url beyond the entry point.

Comment: Why do you need the MVC pages? Wouldn't be cleaner to simply have angular as the UI (with just one html page) and the controllers as the backend? If this was the case, simply move the controllers to a sub-folder (api/) and then, in IIS Management, convert this folder into an application.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more around your actual issue _the client routing it won't let get_ is for me a bit vague. Having said that, I've accomplished this using some url rewriting. This does mean that all your mvc routes need to be separate from your angular ones.

Comment: @Skaparate The MVC pages already exist.  There are 30-50 pages that would need to be converted.  We have made the commitment to get off MVC and into a pure web front end that uses WebAPI on the back end (web page server and web services server as two different servers).  My intent is to convert the pages to Angular one at a time which would have both Angular pages and MVC pages in the same project with the MVC pages disappearing as I went along.  This is much better for testing gradually.  At least, that is the hope.

Comment: @Ahmad By "the client routing" I meant the front page, contact us, about us, registration, and login pages are already written using Angular.  Once you register and login you can navigate to any of the Angular-based pages using the menu with no problem.  You can also navigate to the pages written in Razor/MVC with no problem.  The problem occurs when you try to navigate from a Razor/MVC page back to any of the Angular pages.  I would be very interested to learn more about your "url rewriting" and how you made the "mvc routes" separate from the Angular ones.

Comment: Is your SPA reloading when You navigate from Razor? Are there any errors in the web browser console? You could check if the pages are being transferred correctly from the server (maybe the routes are not right when transitioning from razor?)

Comment: The SPA never gets a chance to load when I navigate from Razor and there are no errors in the browser console. I just went back and tried every transition I could think of and none of them worked.  Good thought, though!  What I am seeing is the request is going back to the MVC server and it doesn't know what to do with the page because it is looking for the appropriate controller and action with no success. Which is weird because I can start the server with any Angular page, but not go back to an Angular page from an MVC page.  Is there a way to tell Asp.Net to NOT use MVC for certain pages?

Comment: This has been valuable discussion for us and I very much appreciate the feedback. We have decided to proceed with converting our one html file to cshtml and nest the angular within it.  This is going to create more work for us later when we are able to kill the MVC since we will have to yank the angular out of the pages.  But it's looking as if trying to get around this is going to cause even more work.  It was worth a try.  Thanks again to everyone!